# What's the difference between Helm list and Kubectl get deployments?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Can someone explain the difference between what you get in the outputs of a helm list and kubectl get deployments command ? I'm running these commands on a sever and some entries appear whether you do a `Helm List` or a `Kubectl get deployments` command and some entries only appear if you run either of the commands. I am pretty new to this obviously. Any help gratefully received

Comment: Did you review the Kubernetes and Helm documentation?

Answer (score 3):

`Helm` is a tool aimed at packaging `Kubernetes` "apps" as a collection of Kubernetes `resources` named `Helm charts`. A deployed version of an Helm chart is called `Release`.

Among the existing resources that can be part of an Helm Chart, one of the most common ones are named `Deployments`.

So when you run `helm ls` you get a list of `helm releases` installed in your cluster.

When you run `kubectl get deployments` you get a list of `kubernetes deployments` that can or cannot be part of an `Helm Release`.